# How to subset a dataframe using R function and use that dataframe later?

Tags: r

I want to subset a data frame using a function as follows.

```
calcScore <- function(y){
        t <- iris[iris$Species == y,]  
        return(t) 
  }
```

when I passed the value as `calcScore('setosa')` it gave an output as below.

```
> calcScore('setosa')
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa
13          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa
14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa
18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa
19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa
20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa
21          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2  setosa
22          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4  setosa
23          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa
24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa
25          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa
26          5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2  setosa
27          5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4  setosa
28          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2  setosa
29          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2  setosa
30          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2  setosa
31          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2  setosa
32          5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
33          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
34          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
35          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
36          5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2  setosa
37          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2  setosa
38          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1  setosa
39          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
40          5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
41          5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3  setosa
42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
44          5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6  setosa
45          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4  setosa
46          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3  setosa
47          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2  setosa
48          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
49          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
50          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

But dataframe t cannot get after that. it gives the following error.

```
> t
standardGeneric for "t" defined from package "base"

function (x) 
standardGeneric("t")
<environment: 0x11be807c>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods("t")  for currently available ones.
```

How can I write a function to subset the dataframe and it should be saved and can be able to access later?

Comment: Assign it to a new object: `mynewdf <- calcScore('setosa')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't assigned the output to anything. In other words, try something like:

```
mynewdf <- calcScore('setosa')
```